# Where in Directory Service OpenAM holds configuration data?

Tags: ldap, openam

We are using an OpenAM as STS and OpenDJ as Directory Service backend. Both Configuration and Data is hold in OpenDJ. We want multiple realm for our B2B clients. Each realm uses a unique OU in directory service. The problem is we need to use our own Front-end and OpenAM REST api to create new organizations. Note that our business clients usually have sub-organization, so it is not convenient to give them access to OpenAM console to make their own sub-realms and assign corresponding OU. I believe realm and its corresponding data store settings must be held somewhere in OpenDJ 9Since I asked OpenAM to hold config there). How can I find them and use LDAP API to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to change configuration directly in the configuration store, because chances are that you will do something wrong and potentially foobar your deployment.

To manage OpenAM configuration you should use the scriptable utilities, such as ssoadm and in the latest versions: amster. If you desperately need an API to work with, then you could use the REST SMS endpoints (fully supported since AM5). To figure out where the endpoints are and how to use them, just open up the API explorer in the admin console.